# to display and hide content in accordian

Tags: jquery, html

I have a basic jquery accordian that displays a list. 
In the current scenario I want some content to be hidden with a button click, and again visible when button is clicked again.
Eg.

```
1) Title 1
2) Title 2
3) Title 3
4) Title 4

<input type='button' value='show/hide'>
```

I want Title 2 to be hidden and visible when user clicks button.

I have used

```
document.getElementById("sec2").style.display == "block"
```

Doing so the accordian gets hidden and visible, but the structure is compromised. i.e it gets visible with "Title 2" being open, whereas i wants it as closed.

It is Standard Jquery Accordian.

```
<div id="accordion">
  <h3 id='sec1'>Section 1</h3>
  <div id='div1'>
    <p>
    Title 1.
    </p>
  </div>
  <h3 id='sec2'>Section 2</h3>
  <div id='div2'>
    <p>
     Title .
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: put your list html code please..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey guys thanks for your response, but everything just doesn't seems to work, so i've finally decided to statically address that. Following is what i have tried.

```
$(function() {
  for(var i = 3; i>=0; i--)
  {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
     active: i,
    });
  }
});
```

This eventually does the trick, closing all the div's and leaving the at the top open, and that too with nice animation....;)

Answer (score 0):

You should try the following (with the collapsible option true):

```
$('#accordion').accordion( "activate" , 2)
```

See more here : http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.8/Accordion

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
<input type='button' id="myButton" value='show/hide'>
```

```javascript
$("#myButton").click(function () {
  $("#sec2").toggle();
  $("#accordion").accordion("option", "active", false);
  //or use $("#accordion").accordion("option", "active", index); to select the option you want to be active
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `toggle` in jquery before than **1.9.x**: see [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wG5n8/)

```
$("#btnToggle").toggle(function(){
    $("#div2>p").hide();
}, function(){
    $("#div2>p").show();
});
```